# What is the meaning of the dollar sign "$" in R function()?

Tags: r, function, scope, lexical-scope

Through learning `R`, I just came across the following code explained [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scope).

```
open.account <- function(total) {
  list(
    deposit = function(amount) {
      if(amount <= 0)
        stop("Deposits must be positive!\n")
      total <<- total + amount
      cat(amount, "deposited.  Your balance is", total, "\n\n")
    },
    withdraw = function(amount) {
      if(amount > total)
        stop("You don't have that much money!\n")
      total <<- total - amount
      cat(amount, "withdrawn.  Your balance is", total, "\n\n")
    },
    balance = function() {
      cat("Your balance is", total, "\n\n")
    }
  )
}

ross <- open.account(100)
robert <- open.account(200)

ross$withdraw(30)
ross$balance()
robert$balance()

ross$deposit(50)
ross$balance()
ross$withdraw(500)
```

What is the most of my interest about this code, learning the use of `"$"` dollar sign which refer to an specific `internal function` in  `open.account()` function. I mean this part :

```
    ross$withdraw(30)
    ross$balance()
    robert$balance()

    ross$deposit(50)
    ross$balance()
    ross$withdraw(500)
```

**Questions:**

1-  What is the meaning of the dollar sign `"$"` in `R` `function()` ? 
 
2-  How to **identify** its attributes in functions, specially for the functions that you adopting from other (*i.e.* you did not write it)?
 
I used the following script

```
> grep("$", open.account())
[1] 1 2 3
```

but it is not useful I want to find a way to extract the name(s) of internal functions that can be refer by "$" without just by calling and searching the written code as  `> open.account()` . 
  For instance in case of `open.account()` I'd like to see something like this:

```
$deposit
$withdraw
$balance
```

3- Is there any reference that I can read more about it? 
tnx!

Comment: See the help file: `?"$"`.

Comment: wanted to add $ is special in that it does partial matches

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The `$` allows you extract elements by name from a named list. For example

```
x <- list(a=1, b=2, c=3)
x$b
# [1] 2
```

You can find the names of a list using `names()`

```
names(x)
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

This is a basic extraction operator. You can view the corresponding help page by typing `?Extract` in R.

Comment: so it's equivalent to using a dot as in most other programming languages?

Comment: @Earlee - Equivalent to the dot notation used in dynamic code of many programming languages. Where `x` is a hash map, and the keys (`"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`) return the values (`1`, `2`, `3`)

Answer (score 41):

There are four forms of the extract operator in R: `[`, `[[`, `$`, and `@`. The fourth form is also known as the slot operator, and is used to extract content from objects built with the S4 object system, also known as a *formally defined object* in R. Most beginning R users don't work with formally defined objects, so we won't discuss the slot operator here.

The first form, `[`, can be used to extract content from vectors, lists, or data frames.

The second and third forms, `[[` and `$`, extract content from a single object.

The `$` operator uses a name to perform the extraction as in `anObject$aName`. Therefore it enables one to extract items from a list based on their names. Since a `data.frame()` is also a `list()`, it's particularly well suited for accessing columns in a data frame. That said, this form does not work with a computed index, or variable substitution in a function.

Similarly, one can use the `[` or `[[` forms to extract a named item from an object, such as `anObject["namedItem"]` or `anObject[["namedItem"]]`.

For more details and examples using each of the forms of the operator, please read my article [Forms of the Extract Operator](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-extractOperator.md).

### Accessing names in an S3 object

Daniel's post includes code for an R object, `open.account()`. As specified, this object is based on the S3 object system, where the behaviors of an object are defined as items within a `list()`.

The code creates three functions within the `list()`, `deposit`, `withdraw`, and `balance`. Since each function is assigned a name, the functions within `open.account()` can be listed with the `names()` function, as illustrated below.

```
> names(open.account())
[1] "deposit"  "withdraw" "balance" 
>
```

Comment: I'd add that `df$first_column` is equivalent to `df[, 1, drop = TRUE]`

Comment: @jiggunjer True, but not neccessary `df[, 1]` is sufficent.