# Why is my dataframe subset of class 'closure'? R studio R version 3.5.3

Tags: r, closures, subset

I am trying to calculate the mean of a subset of my dataframe. However, I have found that my subset returns to be of class 'closure' while I just want it to be a vector. The head of my df may look like:

```
          Date sulfate nitrate ID
1   2002-01-01      NA      NA  8
2   2002-01-02      NA      NA  8
3   2002-01-03      NA      NA  8
4   2002-01-04      NA      NA  8
5   2002-01-05      NA      NA  8
6   2002-01-06      NA      NA  8
```

There are non NA values in both "sulfate" and "nitrate" further down the df.

I have tried to subset using freem[pollutant] rather than freem$pollutant. This doesn't seem to make any difference.

```r
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
    means <- c()
    for(i in id) {
        x <- paste(getwd(), "/", directory, "/", sprintf("%03d", i), ".csv", sep = "")
        freem <- read.csv(x)
        inte <- freem$pollutant
        print(class(frame$pollutant))
        means[i] <- mean(inte, na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    mean(means)
}
```

I expect this for loop to fill the empty vector `means` with the means of the subsets of all selected `monitors` (basically different csv files in my wd)

Comment: Oops: something went wrong in providing you what the head of my subset looks like.

Comment: [pollutantmean](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5br%5d%20pollutantmean)

Answer (score 0):

The `pollutantmean()` function in the OP fails with the following error:

```
Error in frame$pollutant : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Why?

Line 7 includes the following code:

```
 print(class(frame$pollutant))
```

that includes a typo, `frame` instead of `freem`. `frame()` is a function in the graphics package, which has the following consequences.

1. An R function is also a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)),
2. Objects of type `closure` cannot be subset with the [$ form of the extract operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560090/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dollar-sign-in-r-function/47497773#47497773)

Therefore, R generates the closure error message.

Changing Line 7 to `print(class(frame$pollutant))` results in `NULL`, exposing a second error in the code, use of the [$ form of the extract operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560090/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dollar-sign-in-r-function/47497773#47497773) with variable substitution in a function.

In this situation, the correct extract operator is `[[`, because `[` will return an object of type `list()`, which will cause the `mean()` function to return `NA`.

```
inte <- freem[[pollutant]]
```

Note that these changes will result in a working version of `pollutantmean()`, but this version will not pass the quiz in the Johns Hopkins R Programming course on Coursera. Why? The OP code calculates an unweighted mean when the assignment requires a weighted mean.

Since the OP is a homework assignment I won't post a fully corrected `pollutantmean()` function. As a Community Mentor in the JHU Data Science Specialization I am obligated not to post complete solutions to quizzes or project assignments. Instead I refer the student to [Common Mistakes: weighted vs. unweighted means](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-weightedMeans.md) for a detailed walkthrough on the difference between a weighted and an unweighted mean.