# How do I get the number of levels of a factor in a tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse

This seems pretty basic, but the number of verbs in the tidyverse is huge now and I don't know which package to look for this.

Here is the problem. I have a tibble

```
df <- tibble(f1 = factor(rep(letters[1:3],5)),
             c1 = rnorm(15))
```

Now if I use the `$` operator I can easily find out how many levels are in the factor.

```
nlevels(df$f1)
# [1] 3
```

But if I use the `[]` operator it returns an incorrect number of levels.

```
nlevels(df[,"f1"])
# [1] 0
```

Now if df is a `data.frame` and not a `tibble` the `nlevels()` function works with both the `$` operator and the `[]` operator.

So **does anyone know the tidyverse equivalent of `nlevels()` that works on both data.frames and tibbles?**

Comment: Note that `iris[,5]` is a vector but `as_tibble(iris)[,5]` still inherits from a `data.frame`. This is why `nlevels` is failing. Alternatives include: `nlevels(df$f1)`, `nlevels(df[,"f1",drop=TRUE])`, and `nlevels(df[["f1"]])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on the answer from [timcdlucas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2148158/timcdlucas) (and the comments from [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans)), the issue here is the behavior of various forms of the extract operator, not the behavior of `tibble`.  Why? a `tibble` is actually a kind of `data.frame` as illustrated when we use the `str()` function on a tibble.

```
> library(dplyr)
> aTibble <- tibble(f1 = factor(rep(letters[1:3],5)),
+              c1 = rnorm(15))
> 
> # illustrate that aTibble is actually a type of data frame
> str(aTibble)
tibble [15 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ f1: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ c1: num [1:15] -0.5829 0.3682 1.1854 -0.6309 -0.0268 ...
```

There are four forms of the extract operator in R: `[`, `[[`, `$`, and `@`; as noted in [What is the meaning of the dollar sign $ in R function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560090/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dollar-sign-in-r-function/47497773#47497773).

The first form, `[` can be used to extract content form vectors, lists, matrices, or data frames. When used with a data frame (or tibble in the tidyverse), it returns an object of type `data.frame` or `tibble` unless the `drop = TRUE` argument is included, as noted in the question comments by r2evans.

Since the default setting of `drop=` in the `[` function is `FALSE`, it follows that `df[,"f1"]` produces an unexpected or "wrong" result for the code posted with the original question.

```
library(dplyr)
aTibble <- tibble(f1 = factor(rep(letters[1:3],5)),
             c1 = rnorm(15))

# produces unexpected answer
nlevels(aTibble[,"f1"])

> nlevels(aTibble[,"f1"])
[1] 0
```

The `drop =`  argument is used when extracting from matrices or arrays (i.e. any object that has a `dim` attribute, as explained in help for the [drop()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/drop) function.

```
> dim(aTibble)
[1] 15  2
>
```

When we set `drop = TRUE`, the extract function returns an object of the lowest type available, that is all extents of length 1 are removed. In the case of the original question, `drop = TRUE` with the extract operator returns a factor, which is the right type of input for `nlevels()`.

```
> nlevels(aTibble[,"f1",drop=TRUE])
[1] 3
```

The `[[` and `$` forms of the extract operator extract a single object, so they return objects of type `factor`, the required input to `nlevels()`.

```
> str(aTibble$f1)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
> nlevels(aTibble$f1)
[1] 3
> 
> # produces expected answer
> str(aTibble[["f1"]])
 Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
> nlevels(aTibble[["f1"]])
[1] 3
>
```

The fourth form of the extract operator, `@` (known as the slot operator), is used with formally defined objects built with the S4 object system, and is not relevant for this question.

### Conclusion: Base R is still relevant when using the Tidyverse

Per [tidyverse.org](https://www.tidyverse.org), the tidyverse is a collection of R packages that *share an underlying philosophy, grammar, and data structures.*  When one becomes familiar with the tidyverse family of packages, it's possible to do many things in R without understanding the fundamentals of how Base R works.

That said, when one incorporates Base R functions or functions from packages outside the tidyverse into tidyverse-style code, it's important to know key Base R concepts.

Comment: Thank you @Len Greski, an articulate and well thought out answer. I have to accept it for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might need to use `[[` rather than `[`, e.g.,

```
> nlevels(df[["f1"]])
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 2):

`df[,"f1"]` returns a tibble with one column. So you're doing nlevels on an entire tibble which doesn't make sense.

```
df %>% pull('f1') %>% nlevels
```

gives you what you want.