# R extract operator: [ vs $

Tags: r

There are multiple post in the internet regarding the differences and similarities about `[` and `$`. I see some post where `$` is recommended only for interactive use but not for programming. However, I am not sure I understand if this is a preference or there is an explanation behind this idea.

Now lets say I am writing a package or function, if I am extracting an element by name (e.g., `mtcars[["mpg"]]`) why I should avoid using `mtcars$mpg`?

Comment: Programmatic use suggests that the column name will be stored in a variable. So if `nm <- "mpg"`, then `mtcars[[nm]]` works and `mtcars$nm` does not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the dollar sign "$" in R function()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560090/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dollar-sign-in-r-function)

Answer (score 6):

There are two differences that really matter between `[[` and `$`:

1. `[[` - works with strings (i.e. it supports variable substitution), `$` doesn't. If you have `my_var = "mpg"`, you can use `mtcars[[my_var]]`, but there isn't a good way to use `my_var` with `$`.
2. `$` auto-completes, if a partial column name is unambiguous. `mtcars$m` will return the `mpg` column, `mtcars[["m"]]` will return `NULL`. `mtcars$d` will return `NULL` because multiple columns start with a "d".

#1 makes `[[` more flexible for programming - it's extremely common in programmatic use to be working with column names stored as strings.

#2 makes `$` more dangerous - you should not use abbreviated column names in programming, however in interactive use it can be nice and quick. (Though this is largely moot with RStudio's auto-completion features, if you use that IDE.)

Answer (score 3):

`$` does partial matching: if you have a column named `xxx` in a dataframe `dat`, then `dat$xx` will return the `xxx` column (unless you also have a `xx` column). This can be dangerous.

I always use `[["..."]]` for another reason: I use RStudio, and there is a nice highlighting for strings, whereas there's no highlighting with `$`.

Comment: Should be noted that RStudio has an auto-complete feature when using `$` which can be just as handy.

Comment: @Phil Yes, right. But this has effect in interactive mode only.